# Java Application and Windows Firewall

Tags: windows, installation, firewall, install4j, windows-firewall

The Windows Firewall blocks my application to connect to different databases. My application has an installer build using Install4j.
I am wondering if I can set Firewall rules during installation to allow JDBC connectivity, without asking the user to manually add rules or disable the Windows Firewall.

Running the application as an Administrator creates less issues with the Firewall. I can also set the executable to run as an Administrator, but this will prompt the user each time for rights.

Answer (score 1):

In our install4j installer we used the "Run executable or batch file" action to add a firewall rule via netsh:

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="xxx" dir=in action=allow program="xxx" enable=yes
```

Comment: Thank you. I am wondering if for a JDBC client, the dir should be 'in' or 'out'?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, our case was not database-related. I guess your configuration depends on the database you're using. You may also have to configure the firewall settings of the database in addition to the client.